# Show borders when div has neighbor (using bootstrap gird system)

Tags: html, css

how can I make a div give a certain border but only when they have a neighbor using pure CSS?
I am using bootstrap to render the grid.

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>

</div>
```

Example on this picture: [image]

Only show border when div has a neighbor on that side. Basically not the outside borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not any css selectors to handle neighborhood checking.
Instead of it you can use **nth-child** property to handling this style:

```css
/* add border to all sides of all elements */
.row {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/* remove left border of first element of each row */
.row > div:nth-child(5n-4) {
    border-left: none;
}

/* remove right border of last element of each row */
.row > div:nth-child(5n) {
    border-right: none;
}
```